# Get an array from a given dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict1 = {'car': [10000, 'Income'],
    'project': [456, 'Income'],
    'drone': [345, 'Income'],
    'laptop': [678, 'Income']}
```

How should i write the code so that i get all the array of money. eg:[10000, 456, 345, 678]

Comment: Most certainly this is the wrong structure to store this data if you're actually creating this dictionary

Comment: If not, `data = [v[0] for k, v in dict1.values()]`. The order of values will potentially be variable in Python < 3.6

Comment: Lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the dictionary values and store the first value (at index 0) in a temporary list.

```
dict1 = {'car': [10000, 'Income'],
    'project': [456, 'Income'],
    'drone': [345, 'Income'],
    'laptop': [678, 'Income']}

temp_list=[]
for x in dict1.values():
    temp_list.append(x[0])

print(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a one liner:

```
money = [x[0] for x in dict1.values()]
```